# calling a php function from a javascript script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a file where I put all my needed functions. The one that I need is this one:

```
//the functions file
//........
function user_exists($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT('user_id') FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
    return (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

I have included the functions file in my register.php file. What I want to do is call that function from javascript:

```
//the register file (functions file is included here)
<script>
 //.....
      if(user_exists(element.value)){  ........   }
 //.....
</script>
```

I think this can be solved with ajax but how to do it exactly since I'm not familiar with it?

Comment: ajax. Your Target.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: Are you really asking for an AJAX tutorial? Or for someone to hand you the code?

Comment: As above, this screams for an ajax request :)

Comment: i would really appreciate a help in code to understand what am i dealing with.

Comment: assign event,send ajax request to a service page,call this function on your service page,return the response and fetch it back.simple.

Comment: @JanCzarny you should never link to w3schools.... http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: *Research before asking*, this site **is loaded with examples**.

Comment: There are literally too many duplicates to reference.... please just search Stack Overflow before posting

Comment: @JeffShaver You're right, but I think that the w3c at the beginning can help.

Comment: @JeffShaver .... w3schools has plenty of usable information. Just because they're not officially W3C and don't have all the latest information, doesn't mean they're a useless resource.

Comment: thanks for the 'not help' and bad rating, i am running out of time which didn't leave me a moment to learn ajax, any way, i will figure it out alone. close it.

Comment: @user2322972 It's the nature of the site - we're here to help, not code a project for you. There are loads of questions where people have asked for help with AJAX requests for you to look at. Don't get stroppy with us just because we want you to learn

Comment: thanks i understand, i am actually a game dev and this project of web was needed in very limited time, sorry for trouble, and thanks again, i'll search : )

Comment: @SmokeyPHP not a sheep. When I first started getting into all this a while back, I used them as a resource, only to find out (from experience) that a lot of information on there is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to call the PHP function from within the PHP page and print the result. Then connect to it with Javascript/AJAX to get the plain text the PHP prints. Example from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp).

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(){
  var xmlhttp;
  var response;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
      response=xmlhttp.responseXML;
      alert(response);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","register.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```